# DateTimeFormat giving diferent result than SimpleDateformat

Tags: java

Why is `DateTimeFormatter` giving a different result than `SimpleDateFormat`?

```
String dateString = "0819-03-03";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);

System.out.println(sdf.format(date));            

System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.format(
    ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault())
));
```

The output is:

```
0819-03-03    // SimpleDateFormat    
0819-03-07    // DateTimeFormatter
```

I suspect it has something to do with the date being very old.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393619/discrepancy-when-converting-ancient-dates-between-java-util-date-and-java-time-i/52394553#52394553

Comment: tl:dr;, SimpleDateFormat follows Julian/Gregorian standard, Instant follows ISO standard. **Use Date if you intend to display true historical dates as text**, as ISO dates will not match up with the actual dates prior to the Julian/Gregorian switchover.

Comment: Thanks @Compass for finding the duplicate and answering my question